# sql query using results of prior query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I query a table and pull out same column info from foreign keys that reference the same table?  "SELECT name FROM users INNER JOIN gifts ON to=id WHERE id=1;"  will get me the first part but I am unsure on how to get the second part.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the `users` table twice:

```
select
    u1.name `from`,
    u2.name `to`
from gifts g
join users u1 on g.`to` = u1.id
join users u2 on g.`from` = u2.id
where u1.id = 1;
```